# Stokes' Thm. $\vec F = <2y,xz,x+y>$ through intersection of $x^2+y^2=1$ and $z=y+2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I am trying to evaluate $\int_C \vec F \cdot d \vec r$ where

$\vec F = <2y,xz,x+y>$ and $C$ is the intersection of $x^2+y^2=1$ and $z=y+2$.

I believe that $$curl \vec F = <1-x, -1, z-2> $$

The surface is an ellipse, on  the plane $z=y+2$ so the unit normal vector should be

$$\vec n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<0,-1,1>$$

because the dot product is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left(z-1\right)$ I am thinking that we are to evaluate

$$\int \int_S \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left(z-1\right) dS$$

I used $x= \cos\theta, \space y= \sin\theta, z=z$ to evaluate this and got the expression

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_1^3 z-1 \space dz d\theta$$

where I got $4\sqrt{2}\pi$.

Supposedly the answer should be $\pi$.

Can any one help with what my error is?

Comment: The surface over which you calculated your last integral is the cylinder $$x^2+y^2=1,1\leq z \leq 3$$ whose boundry consists of a disjoint union of two circles. In order to use Stokes' Theorem, you need the boundry of the surface in your surface integral to be $C$

Comment: I see that this is precisely I am struggling to understand.  I see that the boundary is the ellipse that is the intersection of the cylinder and the plane and with $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$ one parameter is covered, and I let $z=z$ so that the other parameter is simply the height, z.  I am having trouble visualizing from where to where $z$ should be changing, because I thought it was from the lowest height $1$ to it highest $3$, but apparently that is not right.

Comment: @hyg17 but if you take a cylinder between $z = 1$ and $z = 3$, it has two boundaries. Also that is not the correct representation of the boundary curve we have here.

Comment: @MathLover I see that now.  $z$ does have max and min as I have stated, but the position of z depending on $\theta$ or $y$ is actually the plane itself.  I'm just trying so desperately to simplify the limit of integration I end up messing up the value, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curl is correct, as is your normal vector and your dot product.
The problem I believe is in the integral; I'm not sure where you got that integral or those limits.
The area below the ellipse is the unit circle. With the factor of $\sqrt{2}$ converting $dS$ to $dA$, I would have expected $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}(1 + r sin {\theta})r dr d\theta$$ which gives
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}  \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}sin {\theta} d\theta = \pi$$

Comment: You are quite right, I did it too quickly before. I fixed multiple mistakes that you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Stokes Theorem says $\displaystyle \int_C \vec F \cdot dr = \iint_S curl \vec{F} \cdot dS$

where $S$ is a surface with the boundary and $C$ is the boundary curve of the surface.

You have been asked to find the line integral over the elliptic curve which is intersection of cylinder $x^2+y^2= 1$ and plane $z = y + 2$.

You are applying Stokes' Theorem and instead finding the right hand side of the equation. The easiest way to do so is to consider a disk which has the same boundary as in the question and find flux of the curl of the vector field over the disk.

$\vec{n} = (0,-1,1)$

If you normalize the vector then you have to note that $dS = \sqrt2 dA$  where $dA$ is the projection of $dS$ in XY plane.

Parametrization of the disk surface:

$x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin\theta, z = y + 2 = 2 + r \sin \theta$.

So the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (r^2 \sin \theta + r) \ dr \ d\theta = \pi$

Comment: Thank you so much.  I still seem to be struggling a lot with the relationship between the unit normal vectors and just regular normal vectors.  I really have to practice more to see if I am getting it right.

Comment: as I said if you take unit normal vector, also note that $dS = |\hat{n}| dA$ so that $\sqrt2$ in denominator cancels out. The last time you did not integrate.